# Why variable can be used before defination in scala

Tags: scala

I run scala in Intellij, following is the test code

```scala
  print(test)
  val test = "use before defination"
```

The code can run without warning, though the result is `null` instead of `use before defination`

And then I test some other case

In REPL

```sh
scala>   print(test); val test = "use before defination"
<console>:11: warning: Reference to uninitialized value test
       print(test); val test = "use before defination"
             ^
nulltest: String = use before defination
```

In sbt

```scala
object Helloscala extends App {
    println("Hello Scala")
  print(test)
  val test = "use before defination"
}

------
# result
[info] running how_sbt_work.Helloscala 
Hello Scala
[success] Total time: 7 s, completed Sep 9, 2020, 7:19:23 PM
```

But why is can be compiled ? Thanks

Comment: Just to be sure: this is the complete example code, like you ran that in a scala shell or, or some intellij snippet thing?

Comment: AFAIK - this could work like that if this was a body of a class or trait or object, it wouldn't  compile otherwise.

Comment: If you manage to eval both of them at once. Each eval is treated as body of an object that is initialized and its field imported.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It really depends where this code is located. Consider the following

```scala
object TestVal {
  print(test)
  val test = "use before definition"
}
```

This compiles fine but prints a `null` when initialised. The reason for this is that `val test` becomes a field in `object TestVal` and can be referenced at any place in the code even before initialisation. It will produce a `null` if accessed before value is initialised. One possibility to avoid this is to use `lazy val test` that will initialise a value in this case.

On the other hand, the following code does not compile

```
  def method() = {
    print(test)
    val test = "use before definition"
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

The language allows code that uses a class member before it is initialised, but not a free variable.

This is allowed because in the general case it is impossible to tell when it is happening. So rather than restrict the language more than necessary to avoid it, the language leaves it to the programmer to avoid any problems with initialisation order in this case.